# How do you put a gradient background on ASP.NET menu items?

Tags: asp.net, css, relative-path, menu, absolute-path

The boss wants the master page's menu to look nicer.  I generated my gradient file with one of the tools available on the net, no problem there..

I tried to make a CSS class for each menu item but when I use the background-image directive and the style builder, I get a line like:

```
background-image: url('file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Username/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/WebSites/ThisSite/Images/Gradient.png')
```

...when what I *want* is

```
background-image: url('~/Images/Gradient.png')
```

The first url will, of course, only work when I'm debugging on my local machine - deploy this and I'm hosed.  So many other ASP.NET objects work with "~/" to indicate the top-level directory of the website but my css file doesn't like it and I can't set a background image for the menu control or the menu items - seems like a GLARING omission when I can do it to so many other controls.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think your question title does not reflect what you are really asking. What you want to know is how to stop the style builder from putting absolute file paths on the url property, isn't it?

Comment: That's the question if I'm forced to use the style builder.  The end-result (a gradient background on the menu items) is what I'm driving at.  At this point, I'm ready to rewrite the menu in something else if I have to since it's part of the master page so it's in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there... try this:

```
.menuStyle
{
  background-image: url('/images/BG.gif'); /* Putting a slash in front means its relative to the root.  No slash would be relative to the current directory. */
  background-repeat: repeat-x; /* assuming you have a vertical gradient. */
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is strange..  url('/images/BG.gif'); doesn't work [blanks out the menu items] but url('images/BG.gif'); DOES work - Seemingly the opposite of the comments you included but it clearly IS the solution.  I'm going with what worked - thanks!

Comment: Actually I think I actually might have been mixed up there.  CSS is a little bass-ackwards and even those of us who do it for a living get confused more than we like to admit.  Glad to help.

Comment: Could it be that you're working in a virtual directory and the rooted path doesn't exist?  The other path is relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 4):

The url in your CSS needs to be an absolute (or relative) url and not use the tilde mapping as it is not a server-side component.

```
    background-image: url(  "/images/menu.jpg" );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a glaring omission.  Not an omission at all.  The tilde is an ASP construct.  In your CSS it won't have any meaning.

Comment: What I meant was a glaring omission from the ASP.NET menu properties list.  I can set virtually anything else and so many other controls have "background-image" but the menu doesn't.  That's what I'm trying to compensate for.

Answer (score 0):

One "replace all" operation and you're set.

Replace **file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Username/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/WebSites/ThisSite** with blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried setting the background-image property from CSS in my ASP.Net application (i.e. giving the relative path as described in the post). However, it did not work for me. Later, setting the background-image as `background-image:url('http://localhost:1701/Images/BannerTileBackground.gif');` it did work..

Please let me know what is the correct approach, and the reason why it didn't work before.